# How to store a part of json into another json file

Tags: json, python-3.7

I'm new to json and I have been trying to store a part of a json into another file as I think it's easier to do so then removing unwanted elements. I have seen post on how to get access a part of json and then print them but not saving it. This is my json that I am using.

```
{
  "Id": "Annual report 2019",
  "Date": "25/11/2019",
  "Schools": [
    {
      "Id": "001",
      "Name": "Sunway College",
      "Numbers of teachers": "113",
      "Number of students": "400",
      "Description": null,
      "Partnership": {
        "Schools": [
          "Lancaster University"
        ]
      },
      "Private": true,
      "Annual Revenue": null
    },
    {
      "Id": "002",
      "Name": "Taylors ",
      "Numbers of teachers": "200",
      "Number of students": "600",
      "Description": null,
      "Partnership": {
        "Schools": [
          "CQ University","Thomas More University of Applied Sciences"
        ]
      },
      "Private": true,
      "Annual Revenue": null
    }
  ],
"Created By":"Bobby Williams",
"Date of data collected":"18/8/2019"
}
```

And what I would like to store it in another json file.

```
{
  "Schools": [
    {
      "Id": "001",
      "Name": "Sunway College",
      "Numbers of teachers": "113",
      "Number of students": "400",
      "Description": null,
      "Partnership": {
        "Schools": [
          "Lancaster University"
        ]
      },
      "Private": true,
      "Annual Revenue": null
    },
    {
      "Id": "002",
      "Name": "Taylors ",
      "Numbers of teachers": "200",
      "Number of students": "600",
      "Description": null,
      "Partnership": {
        "Schools": [
          "CQ University","Thomas More University of Applied Sciences"
        ]
      },
      "Private": true,
      "Annual Revenue": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any solution or post that may help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to save part of a json object into a file.

If you want part of a jsonObject (i.e. `schools`) you can assign it as another variable and store that in a file. 
For example

```
def get_part_of_json(jsn_obj, key, file_name): 

    new_jsn_obj = jsn_obj[key] 
    new_str = json.dumps(new_jsn_obj)
    file = open(file_name, 'w')
    file.write(new_str)

def read_jsn_string(string_var): 
    return json.loads(string_var)
```

So when you write `json.dumps` it will convert the json object into a string. And writing `json.loads` you get the corresponding json object.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for answering I have never thought of assign it as a variable I will try it out thank you